# FFmpeg: Is it better to make a application then using ffmepg directly

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libraries

For all my IP camera streams, I use, under Linux, ffmpeg by a bash script which allows me at the same time to manage:

1/ Convert the RTSP streams to HTTP (HLS)  for the "Live" and therefore which generates "m3u8" file and *.ts segments

2/ Backup the stream for archiving (*in increments of 5 minutes*), a cron remove older files (xx days)

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://[IP_CAM01]" -rtsp_transport tcp -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_format mkv "cam01-% 03d.mkv" -c copy -f segment -segment_list cam01.m3u8 -segment_list_flags + live -segment_time 2 -segment_list_size 20 -segment_wrap 20 cam01-% 03d.ts
```

The question I ask myself, and the reason for this message is as follows:

- would there be an interest (memory / cpu / speed) to develop a program (*C/C++/other?*) to do the same thing by using the libraries of ffmpeg?
- or the "gain" and the interest would be so minimal that it is not worth the expenditure of energy and time?

I appeal to your feedback, your opinions, your tips!, and if you had leads (sample) to attack this kind of development, I am interested.

Thank you very much in advance for your feedback.
*(this is my fist question on stackoverflow, Champagne ! ;))*

Comment: The `ffmpeg` executable already is such a program that uses the ffmpeg library internally. Reimplementing that and doing so better than the original authors would be very hard and not worth the effort imo. You could only eliminate the time it takes to parse the arguments, which is minimal compared to the time spent doing the actual operations.

Comment: IIRC with the ffmpeg source code, you can hardwire a specific workflow like the one you're interested in. Are you asking whether it is feasible to write a video transcoding program from scratch or would you like to know whether compiling ffmpeg into your application is better than invoking ffmpeg externally?

Comment: As for the tee muxer usage it should be asked as a separate question, but search first as there are several existing answers involving it.

Comment: Have you discovered any problem with the ffmpeg program?

Comment: @llogan i have change (edit) my fist post, whitout "tee" ou "filter" option i can make with only one process the 2 think (live and backup), i don't know if it was the best way.. but it seem to work well for me

Comment: @alter igel,  I wonder, maybe wrongly, if the development of a program using only the ffmpeg libraries necessary for my need, would allow a more "fast" processing, would consume less memory or even of CPU resource (even if currently it is very light).
I imagine that the "client" ffmpeg embeds a lot of things to meet the multiple needs, which, I think, requires more resources ... but again, I ask myself may be a wrong question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would there be an interest (memory / cpu / speed) to develop a program
> (C/C++/other?) to do the same thing by using the libraries of ffmpeg?
> or the "gain" and the interest would be so minimal that it is not
> worth the expenditure of energy and time?

Almost certainly not.

I very frequently write tools and utilities using the libav* libraries directly. But almost never because I think I can do better than ffmpeg. Its usually because I have a very specific thing that needs to be done, and developing a filter would be more difficult. Or, for example, changing the behavior of how to recover for an error, or changing specific details in how media is packaged.

If ffmpeg is working exactly like it should for your use case, replacing it is not a great idea.